# How do I get data from Arduino to iPhone serially by connecting through Mac?

Tags: ios, arduino, arduino-uno

I am looking to play a game app that I created on my iPhone but do some of the controls through my arduino. Due to limits on what I can do, I need to connect my arduino serially (through USB cable) to my computer and then transfer the data to my iPhone to play the game. Any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: You could use a Bluetooth or wif (TCP/IP) connection between your phone and Mac. You will need an app on your Mac and some code in your iPhone game to make this work

Comment: do you have any links on where to start with that? I tried light blue but I am having trouble with that.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a tiny BLE-Arduino that is natively supported by iOS? For example [redbearlab](http://redbearlab.com/) or [rfduino](http://www.rfduino.com/) controllers are arduino compatible BLE solutions which support iOS.